# "password" text in TextMode="password" in asp:TextBox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I would like to use a `TextBox` for a password, but before the user enters the `TextBox`, I want to see "enter password" as the text.

How is this usually accomplished using ASP.NET? Do I have to create second textbox and manipulate the visibility using Javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If using HTML 5, just use a [placeholder](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder).

With jQuery, there is the [jQuery-watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) plugin:

> Capable of displaying a watermark in password input elements, showing the watermark in plain text, but then switching to password-protected (obscured) mode when focused.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AJAX watermark.

Example can be found here:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx

Comment: While the Ajax library will continue to be supported it is recommended that you use jQuery to achieve UI modifications.

Comment: Microsoft is not updating the AJAX library any more only fixing bugs in the existing framework. Thats why they started officially supporting jQuery and have donated development resources to the project.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it mine and works a dream:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function LoginPassword() {

    document.getElementById("<%= txtTempBox.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("<%= txtPassword.ClientID %>").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("<%= txtPassword.ClientID %>").focus();
}
function LoginPassword1() {


    if (document.getElementById("<%= txtPassword.ClientID %>").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("<%= txtTempBox.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("<%= txtPassword.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";

    }
}
```

```
<div id="dloginPassword">


               <asp:Label ID="hdnLgnPassword" runat="server" Text="Password" Style="display: none;" CssClass="" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTempBox" runat="server"  Text="Password"  
                    onfocus="LoginPassword();" CssClass="Mainlogintextbox txtWaterMark"  />
               <asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Style="display: none;"           
                onblur="LoginPassword1();" CssClass="Mainlogintextbox"  />


            </div>
```

Hope this helps?

Cheers

Steve